# higan says that OpenGL 3.2 is not available, but I should have 3.3

Tags: 14.04, opengl, mesa

I am running Trusty with gnome in crouton on a Toshiba Chromebook 2. I installed higan, and it reports: "Error: OpenGL 3.2 is not available." I googled this, and apparently the problem may be related to some weird way that OpenGL reports its version, distinguishing between "version" and "core profile version". I have no idea what this means.

Here's my glxinfo and mesa-related packages. Please let me know if any more info would help.

`$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL`:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Bay Trail 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
```

`$ dpkg -l | grep -i mesa`:

```
ii  libegl1-mesa:amd64                    10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1                    amd64        free implementation of the EGL API -- runtime
ii  libegl1-mesa-drivers:amd64            10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1                    amd64        free implementation of the EGL API -- hardware drivers
ii  libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64                 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1                    amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
ii  libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64                 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1                    amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX runtime
ii  libglapi-mesa:amd64                   10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1                    amd64        free implementation of the GL API -- shared library
ii  libglu1-mesa:amd64                    9.0.0-2                              amd64        Mesa OpenGL utility library (GLU)
ii  libopenvg1-mesa:amd64                 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1                    amd64        free implementation of the OpenVG API -- runtime
ii  libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:amd64               0~git20131104-1.1                    amd64        Texture compression library for Mesa
ii  libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64            10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1                    amd64        implementation of the Wayland EGL platform -- runtime
ii  mesa-utils                            8.1.0-2                              amd64        Miscellaneous Mesa GL utilities
```

Answer (score 0):

Running `MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.2 MESA_GLSL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=150 higan` will get Higan working.

Answer taken from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/2o9rsd/higan_opengl/).